# Adding edit to draw widget

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I'm trying to add edit(namely Edit.MOVE, Edit.SCALE, Edit.ROTATE, Edit.EDIT_VERTICES, and Edit.EDIT_TEXT) to the draw widget inside CMV. The steps I have taken thus far are:

1- I've defined the edit namespace:
'esri/toolbars/edit',

2- I've added "Edit" inside the function declaration.

3- Created an editTools variable:
drawToolbar: null,
editTools: null,

4- Added the following code inside the post create method to respond to different types of graphics:
this.editTools = new Edit(this.map);

```
        this.pointGraphics.on('click', function(evt)
        {
            console.log("CLICKED ON POINT GRAPHIC");

            event.stop(evt);
            this.activateEditTools(evt.graphic);
        });

        this.polylineGraphics.on('click', function(evt)
        {
            console.log("CLICKED ON POLYLINE GRAPHIC");

            event.stop(evt);
            this.activateEditTools(evt.graphic);
        });

        this.polygonGraphics.on('click', function(evt)
        {
            console.log("CLICKED ON POLYGON GRAPHIC");

            event.stop(evt);
            this.activateEditTools(evt.graphic);
        });

        this.map.on('click', function(evt)
        {
            console.log("CLICKED ON MAP");

            this.editTools.deactivate();
        });
```

5- The activate edit tools method I'm calling above:
        activateEditTools: function(graphic)
        {
            alert("inside activate edit with graphic: " + graphic);
            this.editTools.activate(Edit.MOVE | Edit.SCALE | Edit.ROTATE | Edit.EDIT_VERTICES | Edit.EDIT_TEXT, graphic);
        },

Yet to no avail, any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a problem of scope. When calling `this.activateEditTools`, 'this' is not your widget so the `activateEditTools` method will not be found. Try using lang.hitch like this:

```
this.pointGraphics.on('click', lang.hitch(this, function(evt)
{
    console.log("CLICKED ON POINT GRAPHIC");

    event.stop(evt);
    this.activateEditTools(evt.graphic);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Full answer for those looking for a quick fix:

Inside postcreate:
    `this.editTools = new Edit(this.map);
    this.pointGraphics.on('click', lang.hitch(this, 'activateEditTools'));
    this.polylineGraphics.on('click', lang.hitch(this, 'activateEditTools'));
    this.polygonGraphics.on('click', lang.hitch(this, 'activateEditTools'));
    this.map.on('click', lang.hitch(this, 'deactivateEdit'));`

Outside postcreate:
    `deactivateEdit: function()
    {
        this.editTools.deactivate();
    },
    activateEditTools: function(evt)
    {
        event.stop(evt);
        this.editTools.activate(esri.toolbars.Edit.MOVE | esri.toolbars.Edit.SCALE | esri.toolbars.Edit.ROTATE | esri.toolbars.Edit.EDIT_VERTICES | esri.toolbars.Edit.EDIT_TEXT, evt.graphic);
    },`